# donut icing clipping through donut

Tags: modeling

so I've been watching blender guru's donut tutorial since I am new to Blender and in the icing part it seems to clip through the icing did I do something wrong

[image: the icing clipping]

Comment: This is very common - one of the verts is  is just too far "inwards" and is causing a section of the icing object to "dip through" the donut object (probably made worse by the subdivision surface modifier). In the subdivision surface modifier properties, above where it says "Simple", there is a little icon that looks like a computer monitor - clicking it will toggle the visibility of the modifier in the viewport - turning it off will make it easier to see the "true" position of the verts (if needed). One way or the other - find the offending vert and move it "outwards".

Comment: thx, but now I've got some black lines around the icing, what does "offending vert" mean?

Comment: By "offending vertex", I just mean the vertex that is causing the problem. In your case, it seems that one (or possibly) more vertices are positioned "inside" the donut object, which is causing the whole section of icing to "dip" towards it (subdivision surface modifier tries to "curve" surfaces towards one another - it results in shrinkage and smoothing and some deformation).

Comment: Oh and as an addendum, I'll give the same advice I always give regarding the donut tutorial - _Every_ time you make a mistake, or things don't turn out right, close the program (no saving) and start over _from the very beginning_. It might seem like a pain, but the repetition will make you much faster and more comfortable with blender's systems. By the end, you'll be able to do the _entire_ donut scene in less than 10 mins with no guidance.

Comment: to be honest, this is a much easier solution, so thx, I wish I could mark your comment as an answer but idk how

Comment: Yeah, I don't know if my comment is an "answer" per se, but I'm glad you found it helpful ;)